# Can you arc diff with group as reviewer?

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

we are a lot of people at work and sometimes I just don't remember the user names of all of them, we are all in the same group and I would like to know if it's possible to run something like:

`arc diff --reviewers Developers`

Assuming that Developers is a group that holds all the users that are developers.

I tried this command with no success, is there any other flag that can achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Developers should be listed a Project in Phabricator. If you go to that Project you will see a hashtag for it (probably `#developers`).  if you use that, you should be able to use that.  I have always edited that field in the template and that has always worked for me.  Commandline may react differently, but shouldn't.

Your new command should be `arc diff --reviewers #developers`

Answer (score 0):

assign a list of users once with command:

```
arc diff --reviewers 'brijace, sonagara'
```